# UITextField stops UIGestureRecognizer from working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I've got a view containing subviews of various types on it. At one point, I would like to disable all interactions with the view and subviews, and register instead taps from a gesture recognizer I place on the whole view:

```
tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:revealController action:@selectorrdoSomething:)];
tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
```

While it sort of works, the view below still interacts to all the touches. I then tried adding:

```
tapGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
tapGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesEnded  = YES;
```

It now works EXCEPT - when I tap over a UITextField, this receives the touch INSTEAD of the gesture recognizer. Why is this, how can I stop it? Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted... if you could explain why you are down voting, that would be appreciated. It's not a dumb question, and while the only answer so far was close, it also disables the gesture recognizer on that view as the comment states. Also not sure why that answer is being upvoted when it doesn't solve the problem correctly (but thanks, it was a good idea).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like what you want to do is set the view you don't want receiving the touches `.userInteractionEnabled` property to `FALSE`. Or I am misunderstanding something.

```
yourView.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
```

Comment: If I do that, the gesture recognizer won't work. Thanks though, but I've tried that :)